# Export the list of descriptions in TortoiseHG

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

How to export, in TortoiseHG or Mercurial 3.6.x, all (and only) the descriptions of a project in order to have the list of functionnal changes for a branch or version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly there's no way to do what you want directly in TortoiseHg.
But at command line you can use the `hg log` command while specifying the branch you want, and use the `template` option to indicate that you only want the description.

```
hg log -r branch(MyBranch) --template "{desc}\n"
```

Then you could just pipe the output to a text file if you're looking to use the text elsewhere.

The template keyword `{desc}` gives you the multiline text from the description, if you just want the first line you could use the keyword filter `{desc|firstline}`

See [Chapter 11 of the Mercurial guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html) and the [Mercurial template help](https://www.selenic.com/hg/help/templates) for more information on the available keywords and filtering keywords.